# dovecot: trying to block non-encrypted connections

Tags: encryption, ssl, tls, dovecot

Short and simple -- I don't understand why this is still working.

My configs have

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
ssl = required
```

which, according to the docs, means

> SSL/TLS is always required, even if non-plaintext authentication mechanisms are used. Any attempt to authenticate before SSL/TLS is enabled will cause an authentication failure.

And yet I can still

```
$ telnet 0 110
+OK Dovecot ready.
user xxxxxx
+OK
pass xxxxxx
+OK Logged in.
list
+OK 2 messages:
1 3761
2 4057
.
quit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that plaintext authentication is always allowed (and SSL not
>   required) for connections from localhost, as they're assumed to be
>   secure anyway. This applies to all connections where the local and the
>   remote IP addresses are equal. Also IP ranges specified by
>   login_trusted_networks setting are assumed to be secure.

http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration

Comment: D'oh!  Thank you very much.  Indeed I get the expected error from remote hosts.